Issue migrating from MongoDB to PostgreSQL in Spring Boot
I am working on migrating entity from MongoDB to PostgreSQLand currently there is an issue when migrating field
 private RentingConfiguration renting;

The Entity for MongoDB:
@Document(collection = "products")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;
// etc
    private RentingConfiguration renting;
}

And the entity for PostgreSQL:
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@DynamicUpdate
@Jacksonized
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(buildMethodName = "buildWithoutValidation")
public class ProductMigrated {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;
// etc
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private RentingConfiguration renting;
}

Here is the field looks like in the Mongo Database:
"renting": {     "callToAction": "https://something.smoething.de/geld-anlegen/produkt/c81234a-7g1f-4ab1-777a-2125bt3g8bb5e",     "_class": "com.my.package.product.model.renting.SowRentingConfiguration"   }   

The RentingConfiguration is extended by two classes:
public interface BookingConfiguration {
    @JsonProperty
    String type();
}

public record DocumentRenting(List<ProductLink> documentLinks) implements RentingConfiguration {
    @Override
    public String type() {
        return "documentsAction";
    }
}

public interface LinkRentingConfiguration extends RentingConfiguration {

    default String type() {
        return "linkAction";
    }

    @JsonProperty
    String method();

    @JsonProperty
    String callToAction();
}

And the LinkRentingConfiguration is implemented by two other classes:
public record CrowddeskBookingConfiguration(String callToActionLink) implements LinkBookingConfiguration { ... }

public record EbaseBookingConfiguration(String callToActionLink, String partner) implements LinkBookingConfiguration { ... }

I have a endpoint /mongodb-to-postgresql that migrates all the products from mongodb to postgresql it calls a service that calls a mapper.
The Service calls the Mapper:
 ProductMigrated product = productMapper.productToProductMigrated(product_document);

and the mapper:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT, uses = ObjectMapper.class)
public interface ProductMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "breakdowns", source = "productBreakdowns")
    ProductDto.ProductDtoBuilder productContentToProductDto(ProductContent content);

    ProductAdminDto productToProductAdminDto(Product product);

    Product productAdminDtoToProduct(ProductAdminDto productAdminDto);

    ProductMigrated productAdminDtoToProductMigrated(ProductAdminDto productAdminDto);

    @Mapping(source = "createdDate", target = "createdDate", qualifiedByName = "convertToOffsetDateTime")
    @Mapping(source = "lastModifiedDate", target = "lastModifiedDate", qualifiedByName = "convertToOffsetDateTime")
    @Mapping(source = "renting", renting= "booking", ignore = true)
    ProductMigrated productToProductMigrated(Product product);

All the fields in Entities are mapped except for renting it is just null.
Any suggestions to solve this problem would be appreciated.
